# Fastest, cheapest and easiest way to sell e-books from my own website?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have created a few e-books (pdf) and a website where I want to sell them. My first thought was to only use Paypal but when I realized I had to dig in their API, and it seems to be a lot of work to generate the automatic download of the file when payment is complete, manage the security, etc. I am considering other solutions.

Since I only a few files feels a shopping cart overkill.

The books are relatively cheap, I do not want to pay something every month but a  small fee on each sale (like paypal) is ok.

I also thought if it is worth converting my static site to Wordpress (which I've done before), and use a plugin, for example "Easy Digital Downloads". Or do you suggest any other solution that is cheap and time efficient.

Comment: Its not a question supposed to be here

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/)

Using WooCommerce, which is free, you also get their free PayPal payment module. If you choose to use Stripe instead (which lets you take credit cards directly on your site with SSL certificate installed), that module is free as well.

WooCommerce also has built-in (again, free) capability to handle digitally downloadable products like e-books --> [Documentation here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digitaldownloadable-product-handling/)

All in all, you could probably have a full store setup in less than an hour. They even have a free WooCommerce-ready theme that you can download and try out / customize if you'd like.

Comment: It's a good idea to consider if the question is even appropriate for SO before answering re: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , because you're wasting your time on questions that will be downvoted and closed.